# Toshiba Satellite L855 - Ubuntu 15.+ Synaptics Issue

Tags: 15.04, touchpad, synaptics, 15.10, toshiba

I am running Ubuntu 15.10. (and same issue on the Ubuntu 15.04) 
I recently updated from Ubuntu 14.04(?) and I did not have this issue.

When I try to use the Synaptics finger trackpad, I cannot control the Cursor but I can use the Physical right and left click. I can use an external USB mouse to control Cursor and a remote connection too.

Comment: I'd really like to fix this, I understand I leave details to be desired but please just ask what you need and I will make sure to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was related to BIOS, I was trying to setup WOL(Wake On LAN) just before upgrading to 15.10. I seem to of somehow turned the Touchpad OFF inside BIOS when I went back to turn off WOL. (Hold F4 or 0 to enter BIOS)